# The resistance of a car problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this question:
The resistance of a car whose mass is $750$kg is proportional to its speed. When climbing a slope of $\sin^{-1}(1/25)$ at a constant speed of $10$m/s, the engine works at a rate of $80$kW.

When the car is traveling down the same slope with the engine still working at a constant rate of $30$kW, it has speed $v$m/s at time $t$ seconds after starting it's descend.

Show that 
$$25\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{(10+v)(100-9v)}{v}$$

I know $P = \frac{dE}{dt}$. And since the body is moving on a straight line, I assume it possess a kinetic energy thus $\frac{mv^2}{2} = pt$. How will I proceed to solve this question?

Comment: I added some more work to confirm the equation, but there is an inconsistency with the 80 kw power when ascending. Should this be 60kw?

Comment: Shouldn't this belong to https://physics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: This is not a rigorous proof but it does show consistency for the given equation of acceleration in switching from ascending to descending. Also I took $g = 10\ $ m/s$^2$. It may help in providing insight to a better solution involving energy by taking into account the change in PE by reversing direction.

Taking $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{(10+v)(100-9v)}{25v}$ when the car is descending. In which case at $10\ $m/s.....

$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{20(10)}{25(10)} = 0.8\ $m/s$^2$

When ascending at $10\ $m/s....

$\frac{dv}{dt} = 0 = 0.8 - 2(\frac{F}{m})$

$0.8 - 2\frac{m\cdot g\cdot \sin\alpha}{m} = 0$

$0.8 - 2(10\cdot 0.04) = 0$

$0.8 - 0.8 = 0$

Hence $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{(10+v)(100-9v)}{25v}$ satisfies the change in acceleration from ascending to descending.

Edit: Investigating this a little more when descending

$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{(10+v)(100-9v)}{25v} = 0$ when.....

$(10+v)(100-9v) = 0$

Hence $v = \frac{100}{9}$ m/s

At $v = \frac{100}{9}$ m/s the energies must balance....

$30 000 = Rv^2 - mg\frac{v}{25}$

$30 000 = \frac{10000}{81}R - 750(10)\frac{100}{9\cdot25}$

$30 000 = \frac{10000}{81}R - 3333.3333$

$33333.3333 = \frac{10000}{81}R$

$R = 270$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{F}{m} = \frac{\frac{P}{v}}{m}$$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{\frac{30 000 - 270v^2 + 300v}{v}}{750}$$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1000 - 9v^2 + 10v}{25v}$$

Hence:
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{(10 + v)(100 - 9v)}{25v}$$

This equation also works when ascending at $-10$ m/s giving $\frac{dv}{dt} = 0$ but is not consistent with a power of $80$ kw

Comment: Thanks. But can you please elaborate further as to how mgv/25 is gotten, taking from 3000 = Rv^2 - mg v/25. How did you come about the v/25. ? Thanks

Comment: v/25 is the change in height per second due to the slope. Power 30000 = Rate of change of energy = Force times velocity - Rate of change in PE. Force = Rv (resistance proportional to speed) and Rate of change in PE = mgv/25. This part determines the value of the constant of proportionality R =270 between the resistance force and velocity. So Fr = 270v. Once you have this, then figuring acceleration as a function of velocity is easy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information

Comment: Hello prof, I have been asked to find the time for the car to reach the speed of 10m/s from rest on it's path down the slope. I try solving it but had an answer of 0.394, please is this correct, if not please elaborate.

Comment: I used an on-line anti-derivative solver to get a general solution and then I figured the specific solution to be t = (-250ln(|9v - 100|) - 225(|v + 10|))/171 + 9.7624 and for the definite integral between v=0 and v=10 I get t = 2.4543 seconds.